# Сервер для Android online игры

Tags: python, база-данных, unity3d, сервер

Всем привет. Я пишу онлайн игру на мобилку, игра на юнити, сервер думал писать пайтон. Итак, мое понимание о сервере: Сервер - это некий коннектор клиента и базы данных который принимает запросы от игроков, делает все нужные проверки получая данные из базы данных, затем при успехе записывает или изменяет данные в базе и возвращает игроку что он хотел получить от сервера. База данных - также некий, но уже хранилище всех данных игроков, которые сидит и записывает друг повыше. Сервер2 (тот который покупают) - компьютер у которого есть 2 ip адреса, 1 из них его личный, 2 общедоступный.

Какой сервер у меня: У меня игра на C#, сервер на Python, база данных - .ini файлы, получаю или записываю данные в базу данных с сервера через ConfigParser. Покажите слепому его ошибки

А, и еще я задумался над тем, как работают много серверов в одной игре, как они между собой связаны, и есть ли некая общая база данных. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Сервер — это устройство, которое принимает какие-либо данные и возвращает их кому-то, кто тоже подключён к этому серверу. Если Вы пишете онлайн игру, тогда Вам нужно подключать всех игроков к одному серверу. Большинство из них платные, есть бесплатные, например Lacewing - [ссылка](https://dark-wire.com/relay/)

---

Вы должны каждого игрока при запуске игры подключать к серверу, и отправлять на него, например, координаты персонажа с условием, что эти данные сервер отправит на все устройства подключённые к тому же серверу и тому же каналу. Вы на каждом устройстве получаете эти данные и отображаете игрока.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под отправить на все устройства? Просто при следующем запросе на сервер с боку игрока со всему нужными ему данными также вернуть нужные данные нового игрока?

Comment: Всё зависит от системы, с которой Вы работаете. Когда я делал мультиплеер на Android, мне приходилось с каждого устройства отправлять на сервер запрос на получение данных, которые возможно там есть. Это плохой способ, но другой возможности у меня не было, из-за недостатка движка. Вы можете либо делать так же, либо отправлять на сервер вместе с данными сигнал, чтобы он отправил всем другим игрокам эти данные, это проще и быстрее.